# How is authentication token used to access user data

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, jwt

I am trying to understand how token based authentication strategy uses the token (e.g.: JWT) to access the data specific to a user. All I see explained in search results is the part when the user supplies the username and password and then the token is created and verified with each subsequent call.

Le't say I have a Node.JS service with two MongoDB collections: *Users* and *UserMessages*. Each entry from *UserMessages* contains a *UserID* and a *Message*.

If an authenticated user wants to see all the messages pertaining to that user, how do I (programatically) know how to filter the correct messages? **How do I make the correlation between the token and the user identity** (e.g.: *UserID* or anything else that helps identify the user) that I need for querying the message collection in the next step?

I just wish to understand the concept. I couldn't find anywhere a clear example where the user identity is obtained in code. [Example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens):

```
apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') 
        || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 
                    'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;    
                next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JWT contains a payload.

Typically, you put the user's ID in this payload. You can put anything you like in there, but since the token is sent on every request you want to keep the payload small. Also, because the JWT is base-64 encoded, anyone can decode the token and see the contents of the payload.

However, because only your server knows the "secret" for the JWT, no one can alter the payload or otherwise create a phony JWT... your server will consider such tokens invalid.

The above code seems to be decoding the payload and storing it on the `req` object.  When it decodes the JWT it is also verifying the signature, so if the decode is successful you can trust the data in the payload.  Now you can use the user ID from the payload to get the data you desire.